# Volume of revolved solid using shell method: finding height

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The problem that I am working with is:

> Find the volume of the solid of revolution formed by rotating the region $R$ bounded by $y = 4+ x^2,\;x=0,\;y=0,\;and\;x=1$ about the line $y=10$

I have the following so far (using the shell method):
$$V=\int_a^b2\pi\,r\,h\,dy\\r = 10-y\\c=2\pi(10-y)\\
h=?$$
$$V=2\pi\int_0^1(10-y)hdy$$
I've been searching for an example in my book where there is a horizontal rotation that is not over the x-axis, but I have had no luck.

Would the height just be $\sqrt{y-4}$ or would it be $10-\sqrt{y-4}$ and why?

Comment: Do you really want to use Shells? The "Washer" method is less work in this case.

Comment: Have you tried sketching the volume to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that you *really* want to use the Shell Method. In that case, we will look at a thin strip of width "$dy$" at height $y$, and rotate it about $y=10$.

The complication is that the thin strip has a different shape from $y=0$ to $y=4$ than it does from $y=4$ to $y=5$.

From $y=0$ to $y=4$, the radius is $10-y$, and the "height" of the cylindrical shell is $1$. Thus the volume obtained by rotating that part is
$$\int_{y=0}^4 2\pi(10-y)(1)\,dy.$$
From $y=4$ to $y=5$, the radius is still $10-y$, but the "height" of the cylindrical shell is $1-x$, that is, $1-\sqrt{y-4}$. The required integral is
$$\int_{y=4}^5 2\pi(10-y)(1-\sqrt{y-4})\,dy.$$
Calculate the two integrals, and add.

**Remark:** For this problem, the Method of Washers is less work. Take a cross-section "at" $x$ perpendicular to the $x$-axis. The outer radius is $10$, and the inner radius is $10-y$, that is, $10-(4+x^2)$. The volume is 
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \pi(10^2-(6-x^2)^2)\,dx.$$

Comment: "Shells" and "Washers"? Is this a new thing in introductory calculus?

Comment: Cylindrical Shells has been a standard name for quite a few years in North American calculus texts. Washers is newer.

Comment: Look at the picture. The solid is a cylinder with an odd-shaped hole removed from it. The radius of the cylinder is the distance from $y=10$ to the $x$-axis, which is $10$. So the outer radius of the shape is $10$. The inner radius, basically the cross-sectional radius of the hole, is $10-y$, which is $6-x^2$ (I mistakenly had $4-x^2$ there, can't subtract).

Comment: Okay, I've got it now. Thanks again, Andre. You've been a huge help today.

Comment: You are welcome. There is a limited number of themes in these volume questions, so after you have good control over these, things will become quite easy. A good grasp of the geometry is essential. One has to visualize (for Shells) the thin strip rotating.

Comment: $10-y = 10 - 4 + x^2 = 6-x^2$?

Comment: $10-y=10-(4+x^2)=6-x^2$.

Comment: Of course. Long day. Thanks.